# Paired t-test or two sample t-test with unequal variance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, paired-data

I'm attempting to compare some economic forecast errors across institutions. I want to see if the mean absolute error is different from one institution to the other. Since the forecast errors apply to the same year for each institution, I was thinking about using a paired t-test, but I'm not sure if I should here. Is it appropriate to use in this scenario, or would a two sample t-test assuming unequal variance be better?